# Hair pointing inside mesh

Tags: particles, hair

[file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0s08236burc5wy/01_coyote06.blend?dl=0)

I have hair pointing inside the mesh on the legs of this Coyote. I tried viewing the normals and they all appear to be facing the correct direction. Any ideas?

Comment: it also is the worst on the legs which i have hidden in the file sorry please enable that to see